# LDAP user does not exist when running 'su'

Tags: rhel, ldap, sssd

I'm attempting to set up LDAP authentication according to the instructions in Sander Van Vugt's RHCSA/RHCE book for RHEL7. In chapter 6 he explains that when using `authconfig-tui` the `FORCELEGACY` option is set to `yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig`. This is supposed to configure `nslcd` instead of `sssd`.

I do not see this happening. Perhaps it was that way in 7.0 or even 7.1, but in 7.3 the option is set to `no` after using `authconfig-tui`.

If I put aside the `nslcd` vs `sssd` confusion and attempt the complete the exercise which leads to running `su - lara` to authenticate via LDAP to said user, I merely get:

```
su: user lara does not exist
```

I've verified that the FreeIPA server is answering queries using `ldapsearch` and in doing so, confirmed that the user is in LDAP. It seems to me, though, that `su` is not authenticating against LDAP, but instead `/etc/passwd`.

My `PAM` `system-auth` configuration includes the `sssd` entries that seem to be necessary:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam.sss.so
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

My `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file contains:

```
passwd:    files sss
shadow:    files sss
group:     files sss
```

The `sssd` service is active.

There aren't any log entries in `/var/log/*` or `/var/log/sssd/*`. In fact, none of the `sssd` logs contains anything.

**EDIT**

After some reading I'm still no closer to a solution to this, however, I do have more information.

I am able to authenticate as user lara if I `ssh` into the LDAP server. So I know that LDAP is actually working.

I also looked at the `PAM` config for `su`. This is pulling in the `system-auth` file:

```
auth        substack        system-auth
account     include         system-auth
password    include         system-auth
session     include         system-auth
```

so it should be making use of the `pam_sss.so` module implicitly.

Still can't sort it out, though.

**EDIT 2**

Being able to log into the IPA server either locally or via SSH with user lara, I decided to compare the pam files on it with those on the client. The only difference I was able to determine is that the client contained `broken_shadow` with the `pam_unix.so` account entry. I removed it and even rebooted but it didn't fix anything.

How do I disable `broken_shadow`? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Have a look at the contents of `/etc/pam.d/login` (which is clearly working) versus `/etc/pam.d/su` (which is likely wrong in some way)

Comment: @steve `/etc/pam.d/login` contains the same includes and substack statements as `/etc/pam.d/su`. I've also attempted to log in directly as user lara on the client side. It didn't even attempt to check LDAP. It simply said `Login incorrect` because the local user doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you try to login ldap user thru phpldapadmin ? Before you used pam for ldap authentication.

Answer (score 1):

This may be unrelated, but I'm following the same course (with a client Server of my creation) and managed to fix it by doing the following:

1. Checking everything matched what I'd set in authconfig-tui in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
2. Setting the permissions on /etc/sssd/sssd.conf to 0600 (it worked immediately after that) - I'm unsure why this made a difference, given that it only grants user R/W, but I found it under an Oracle guide for RHEL7 SSSD Client configuration: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/ol7-sssd-ldap.html

EDIT: Possible explanation: https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/1413